# React navigation shared element transition forward works but does not 'transition' back

Tags: react-native, animation, react-navigation-v6, react-navigation-shared-element

I'm having a nested stack with the "react-navigation-shared-element" (0.8.4, Expo sdk 37, react native 0.70.5, react-navigation 6)

Clicking on a given card results in the proper transition to the card as expected. However, clicking on the back navigation button to go back to the list of cards, the animation does not transit or follow, and instead a typical 'go back' is happening--without animation.

Please check out the video and the reproducible snack below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JFmNkC9nxTOVqVmQXBNM3OIzzgN_Vpjr/view?usp=sharing

snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@onrun/sharednavigation?platform=ios